# Abelianization of a group given by a presentation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $G = \langle x,y\mid x^3 = y^5\rangle$. How can I compute the abelianization of such a group?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with Smith normal form?

Comment: No I am not, but I will check thank you!

Comment: Consider adding a new element $z=x^3=y^5$.  By commuting terms around you should be able to present every element of the abelianization in the form $x^py^q$, and then in the form $x^iy^jz^k$ with $0\leq i\lt 3$ and $0\leq j\lt 5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the relation $xy = yx$ then all elements can be written in the form $x^ay^b$ with $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Moreover $x^ay^b = e$ precisely when $(a, b)$ is a multiple of $(3, -5)$.  This means that your group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2 / \mathbb{Z}(3, -5) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.  (The "precisely" might need some explaining.)

Comment: Thanks! Why is $\mathbb Z^2/\mathbb Z(3,-5)\cong \mathbb Z$? Should not it be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/3 \oplus \mathbb Z/5$?

Comment: @Ferenc: This is because $\gcd(3,5) = 1$.  In this case you have for example $\mathbb{Z}^2 = \mathbb{Z}(3,-5) \oplus \mathbb{Z}(1, -2)$.